# ssh-agent Won't Stay Alive on CentOS 7

Tags: ssh, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 box with multiple users. All users use jailed shell. I'm using different users for each site/account hosted on the server for security reasons (sandboxing), but I have control over all users.

I have an ssh keypair from my local machine to the remote, which works without issue (password auth is turned off on the remote, if that matters). Each user has a second unique ssh keypair used to connect to a remote VCS repository.

I can ssh from my local machine into each user without issue. However, connecting to the VCS repo fails from each user because it doesn't recognize the key. If I `ssh-add <mykey>`, it returns `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` I then have to `eval $(ssh-agent)` and add the key again, after which the ssh connection to the remote VCS works. The next time I connect to the remote, I have to repeat this process.

My question is: what is happening that causes ssh-agent to die between sessions? And what can be done keep it active?

Thanks!